# Edit GnuPG encrypted file with no graphic interface

Tags: command-line, gpg

I am trying to edit an encrypted file remotely, with no X-forwarding.

Locally, when I launch:

```
emacs myfile.gpg
```

A pop-up window opens in which I enter my passphrase. I'd like to have something similar in "command line only", with no window opening; when I do that through SSH with no X forwarding, it gets stuck (all I have is a blank `emacs` in which I cannot do anything).

I took an example where I am trying to edit a file, but I encounter the same problem with any action requiring my passphrase like

```
gpg --decrypt myfile.gpg --output myfile.txt
```

Comment: The gpg-agent running your local system is not accessible in the remote ssh connection.  Are the pgp keys needed for file decryption stored on the remote system (probably not advisable) or the local system (most likely)?

Comment: The pgp keys are on the system that I access.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the pinentry mode:

```
gpg -d --pinentry-mode loopback my_file.gpg -o myfile.txt
```

Now it should ask for the passphrase via command-line.

More details on [*How to force GPG to use console-mode pinentry to prompt for passwords?*](https://superuser.com/a/1259632/942947).

Comment: Thanks, it partially answers my question; I can now indeed enter the passphrase via the command-line and see the content of the file.

Comment: Warning to those who test this out, and on decryption find that GPG shows you the contents without asking for the passphrase! It caches symmetric passphrases unless you also add the --no-symkey-cache option.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [francescop21's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482809/42855), I found how to configure globally the pinentry mode (for GnuPG version 2.1+): I simply had to create (or edit) `.gnupg/gpg.conf` file in which I added the following line:

```
pinentry-mode loopback
```

Now I can seamlessly open my file with `emacs` (or any other application). But I am still stuck with GnuPG version lesser than 2.1.

Comment: With `gpg` 1.x you don't need to change pinentry mode as it should always ask for passphrase via command-line.

Comment: I have the problem with gpg 2.0; pinentry-mode is not recognize (neither as a command-line argument nor as an entry in the configuration file). I can find the argument in gpg 2.1+ manpage but not in gpg 2.0.

Comment: For gpg 2.0, I found the command-line option `--passphrase-fd 0` that allows me to interact with a file with no graphical interface, but it does not work if I put it in my `.gnupg/gpg.conf` file.

Comment: Take a look at [*Disable gnome from asking passphrase in GUI when using ssh and gpg from terminal*](https://askubuntu.com/a/858947/873160).

Comment: I tried to set up my gpg-agent setting `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` in `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, but it did not work either. As for my test with `passphrase-fd` in `.gnupg/gpg.conf`, when I try to open my file with `emacs` it gets stuck and all I can do I close my current terminal.

Comment: How does `emacs` invoke `gpg`?

Comment: Since I use Emacs 23 on this machine, I guess it uses EasyPG, perhaps I should look on this direction. Note that with Emacs 25 and GnuPG 2.1+ it did not have to configure anything on Emacs side, it takes directly into account `gpg` configuration.